# displaying precision value.... in flex text box

Tags: apache-flex, precision

in my flex application im retrieving a data from database.....
(ie) price as **decimal(18,4)...**

Now i need to display the retrieved value in an flex text box

textbox name is price.text...
obj is  object name...

i have used the following in code...it not works...

```
    price.text = obj.Price.toPrecision((18,4));
```

.kindly give ur suggestions folks....

Comment: Have you tried the `NumberFormatter` class?  Does that do what you want?  What is the data type of `Price`?

Comment: there is not such thing as 'decimal(18,4)' in Flex.  If anything, it's a number, and you're giving it an invalid precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`NumberFormatter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/NumberFormatter.html). To follow your example, you would declare a `NumberFormatter` like so:

```
<mx:NumberFormatter
    id="myNumberFormatter"
    precision="4"/>
```

or in Actionscript:

```
var myNumberFormatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter;
myNumberFormatter.precision = 4;
```

Then use the `NumberFormatter`'s format function on your value:

```
price.text = myNumberFormatter.format(obj.Price);
```